# Asking questions about specific bugs in large projects

Tags: discussion, questions

I have been learning C++ recently and frequent Stack Overflow for advice on a project I'm working on. The project has become rather large.

Some of the bugs and coding cases I encounter seem so specific to the project that they cannot be easily replicated unless they function under the same context and assumptions as the larger project. I often find either I ask a question that

1. Gets a great answer but for one reason or another isn't applicable (some other part of the project inhibits the solution's use). Typically this is because I have managed to distill the question but have removed the project's scope.
2. Gets few or no answers at all. This is generally due to including a mountain of code or general (but seemingly necessary) verbosity.

What would be some tips or suggestions to ask better questions about large projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other reliable approach to solve such problems - you have to narrow them down and come up with smallest possible case showing the problem. You can either do it yourself or make someone else doing so by:

- paying them cash (not SO route, generally very expensive)
- paying reputation on SO with bounty/upvote (requires question to be on-topic, which pretty much make this route useless)
- make problem look interesting and entertaining (rarely applicable for this type of questions). This may work better with face-to-face communication inside your team rather than faceless SO post.
- rely on dumb luck that someone on SO happens to seen something similar (low effort to post, not reliable in long term due to likely question-ban for "no research shown"/"too broad" posts)

but none of the approaches I know would fit nicely on SO. Essentially you'd be knowingly posting a bad question in hope someone will give an answer - such posts are really not welcome and likely land asker in question ban.

As alternative if you are stuck narrowing the problem down you can ask "how to debug/narrow down XXXX problem" question. Such question is likely to be on "too broad" side, but sometime you may be able to narrow the context of the issue enough to be in scope for SO and generally you'll have done enough research by that point so the post can easily include enough indications that you did so.

Comment: CPUs get paid in cache, but every human I know wants cash ;-)

Comment: This is really actionable advice. Specifically the debugging, it's an area where I'm weak and learning how to learn I think is the right avenue. This targets the crux, which is not knowing what the problem actually is.

Comment: You didn't mention to search on Stack Overflow first (before asking) for similar problems/error messages/concepts.

Answer (score 7):

No matter how big your project is, to ask a question you need to reduce the problem to a manageable size. It's a very important skill to learn, since it will help you solve most of your problems by yourself.

And if you haven't fixed the problem by yourself, in the process you will have learnt more about the issue to ask a more focused and better informed question; which will allow other users to better help you.